# Visual Studio 2013 or 2015 Apache Cordova Solution Store Upload fails

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2015, publish, windows-store

I developed the solution in VS 2013 and then moved it to VS 2015.

I had enough troubles due to several inconsistencies, at the end without answers, with alternatives to those have no answers somehow I am able to finish my app.

I built the app targeting Windows Phone Universal and published the app to store from VS 2013.

I am now trying with 2015.

Step 1 Associate with Stores Quits VS 2015. NO clue why!!!!

Skipped that and continue with Create App Package. Successfully built it.

Uploaded the package. Upload was success with new submission but reflecting old version of package.

Manually Submitted.

I am getting the following error.

"A previous submission for this app was released with a Windows Phone 8.1"

I am unable to figure out the reason as I have been targeting to the same version Windows Phone universal in VS2015 as I did in VS 2013.

None of the documentation is helping here.

Any clues how to resolve would be very helpful.

Honestly, Microsoft must consider paying me or any other for this kind of testing services . :-)

Thanks

Comment: The difference i have found now is, the appxbundle name from 2013 was different from present 2015. Second strange i found was, store is not showing the option to delete the appxbundle which was available earlier. Any body from micrsoft has idea about this!!!!!

Comment: Now there is a different behavior from earlier. It has accepted my package but not removed the earlier package. Is the team at Microsoft working to fix the problem while after deploying the erroneous system into production and fixing on public complaints

Comment: One thing is sure man now, Microsoft team is deploying erroneous systems and fixing them on public complaints here and in their forums. Otherwise, i have not made a single change anywhere but repeatedly building and publishing the same code in the sequential steps but the store behaves differently.